# Excel VBA to repeat founding

Tags: excel, vba

Goal:

1. Search Sheet1 for keywords in column 18 (keywords:case,etc.)
2. Once keyword is found, offset (0,-11)
3. enter the given value C1008 in respective cell.
4. and repeat the same till it completes full column (about 1500 rows)

I am not able to perform 4th step.
And I need multiple keywords to search and perform the same steps.

Program:

```
Sub RCIM()                                    
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim aCell As Range

    Range("A1").Select
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    With ws
        Set aCell = .Columns(18).Find(What:="case", LookIn:=xlValues, _
                    LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _ MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
        If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
            aCell.Offset(0, -10).Value = "C1008"
        Else
            MsgBox "Not Found"
         End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want just to repeat your code use a loop statement like this:

```
Sub RCIM()                                    
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim aCell As Range
    DIM isTimetoExit As Boolean
    Dim currentRow As Long   'Counter of Rows
    Dim KeyWord as String

    Range("A1").Select
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    With ws

        isTimetoExit = False
        currentRow = 1            'If you start from row 1
        KeyWord = "case"

        DO
            ' 
            Set aCell = .Columns(18).Find(What:=KeyWord, LookIn:=xlValues, _
                            LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _ MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

            If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
                aCell.Offset(0, -10).Value = "C1008"
            Else
                MsgBox "Not Found"
            End If
            '

            ' Whit a condition go out of loop
            isTimetoExit = NOT (Trim(.Cells(currentRow, 1).Value & "") = "")
            If (isTimetoExit) THEN EXIT DO

            'Go for next row
            currentRow = currentRow + 1
            ' And set the keyword to your new value;
            KeyWord = "next case"  'But I don't know where are those KeyWords stroes !?
        LOOP
    End With
End Sub
```